# Undefined Offset / PHP error

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

I'm using a WordPress plugin that contains this function, but the plugin developers are not being particularly quick to respond.

It is supposed to get the video ID from a YouTube URL, but instead I'm getting an "Undefined Offset: 1" error. Is there a coding error that I'm missing?

Here is the function:

```
function youtube_id_from_url($url) {
    $pattern =
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        $%x'
        ;
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if (false !== $result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried doing a `print_r` to see what the array `$matches` looks like, and it seemed to just be an empty array, so I tried echoing `$result` and it returned 0, which would mean that `preg_match()` isn't finding a match, correct? If so, I can figure out what's wrong with `$pattern` that would make it return 0.

UPDATE:
Apparently there's some other function that is taking the URL and making a link out of it and then saving that as the `$url` variable. If I echo the `$url` variable it prints as `<a href="youtube url">youtube url</a>.`

So that explains the error but how can I modify the regex to accommodate the html markup?

Comment: Can you add the url that is causing the error?

Comment: `preg_match` will never return boolean `false` (unless there's an error). Typically it returns a `1` or a `0`. The check should simply be `if ($result) {`

Comment: Working fine for me (other than what @Phil said): https://3v4l.org/eTvqp

Comment: This expression does not account for extra query parameters such as `&feature=youtu.be`. Try changing the last line to `&?.*$%x'`

Comment: Please show youtube URL

Answer (score 1):

preg_match will only return FALSE if an error occurs, and in this case you're probably wanting to know if there was either matches or no matches. So you should be able to switch the line:

```
if (false !== $result) {
```

to

```
if ( isset( $matches[1] ) ) {
```

or

```
if ( $result && isset( $matches[1] ) ) {
```

As Phil points out, all you really need is:

```
if( $result ) {
```

Full revised function complete with Phil's modification to the regex:

```
function youtube_id_from_url($url) {
    $pattern =
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        &?.*$%x'
        ;
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if ($result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `$matches` will always be set (unless `preg_match` returns `false`). If `$result` is *truthy*, you don't need to check `$matches`

Comment: $matches might always be set, but will $matches[1]? Obviously not, or he'd not be getting that error.

Comment: If the pattern matches anything, `$matches` will have two elements due to the non-optional capturing group

Comment: That for sure noteworthy. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: This is just returning as false now, but please see the update I just added to the original question.